# Product which allows user input which take price from this

Tags: custom, ce-1.7.0.1

Currently working on a website were some products require user input for example Width and Height

From this the m2 price (for example 14) is done between the width and height given by the user and then the quantity is added.

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Did you manage to resolve your issue?

Comment: Been away from this project and only just saw the answer. Will update once I've looked into it.

Comment: you could have used following third party script that allows you to calcuate price based on user input in different units, area, volume, width , height etc. http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/dynamic-square-foot-pricing-calculator.html

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Found a way to do it with the aid of a freelancer, will edit this post once I have more details.

Answer (score 2):

I've dealt with this problem before on [this shop](http://www.import-tegels.nl/castelvetro-misingi-suber-20x80.html) (link for reference) where you order tiles by the box but it allows you to fill out m2 to calculate how many you need.

I suggest adding the product in the backend with the price of 1 square meter, so when someone orders 4m2 he just orders 4 items. Then in the frontend modify the html of the quantity box to have 2 inputs for width and height and translate that with some simple javascript to the hidden `qty` box.

It's an easy fix but works great. Alternatively, if you need to have the width and height mentioned with the item in the order make custom options for the product with that name and use those inputs to calculate quantity.

This way you're staying close to the normal Magento functionality meaning you cal still apply special prices or even tierprices when people order large amounts of square meters.

Comment: Thanks for taken the time to Answer. The issue is that the height and width is needed for the poster and the qty for the amount of poster as these size.

Comment: I’m facing a similar issue. We have some old gift card system installed and I need to find a way to make it purchasable. Right now our gift cards are very much used so purchasing a new GC module might not work. I’m going try this and see what happens.